# Is 7:30-8:15am the best time to have sex?

Tags: medical-science, sexuality

[Russian language media](http://www.mignews.com/mobile/article.html?id=150817_221512_97307) (as usual, citing usual unnamed "[british researchers](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5#.D0.A1.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.82.D1.8B.2C_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.B2.D1.8F.D1.89.D1.91.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.BC_.D1.83.D1.87.D1.91.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.BC)"), reported that **7:30-8:15am is the best time to have sex**.

> Британские исследователи назвали лучшее время для занятия сексом. По мнению специалистов, любовными утехами лучше заниматься, начиная с 7:30 и 45 минут после этого

My translation:

> British researchers stated the best time for sex. According to experts, it is better to engage in romantic pursuits starting from 7:30 in the morning and for 45 minutes after that

Is that reporting accurate to the research? How sound is that research (the article mentioned 1000 participants in the study) and is it supported by other studies?

The article cited the acclaimed scientific publication "The Sun", so given that it's a translation of a presumably-tabloid retelling of a press release (at best, may be there were other transmission nodes on the way) I'm skeptical of the fidelity of the final reporting.

Comment: I think this is the same claim, in English: https://youtu.be/k3pdeyAtGUA

Comment: Currently, I don't think the question contains an empiric claim. Best time for what effect? 
Cardio benefits? Muscle building? Length of orgasm? Stability of a romantic relationship?

Comment: @Christian - the question is based on an article citing specific (supposedly) research.

Comment: @user5341 you posted here alludes to research, but doesn't have a verifiable claim.   _"Peanuts are the best."_ How could you falsify or verify that statement?  Perhaps translating more of the article would provide a claim that can be examined.  _"Peanuts are the best source of pheromones for attracting blond water skiers.   According to experts, if you want to increase the chances of double jointed offspring, it is better to engage in romantic pursuits starting from 7:30 in the morning and for 45 minutes after that."_

Comment: Best for what? Enjoyment? Relationship improvment? Fertility? Lack of fertility? Secrecy?

Comment: I found the Sun article that recommends 7:30 [here](https://www.thesun.co.uk/archives/health/297868/730am-time-to-make-love/) (not to be confused with [the articles where they recommend other times](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Athesun.co.uk+best+time+to+have+sex)). It would be best to rewrite your question to focus on the actual, solid claim that they made: "Research in Italy found it is also the time most couples are likely to orgasm – and conceive."

Comment: What @DJClayworth said: best for *what*? You - or something - cannot just be "best", you can only be best *at* something.

Comment: You do realise that when it's 8 in the morning in Moscow it's actually [5 O'clock in the morning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noLrCDzAp5M) in London?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly true, for males. This [entertaining TED talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2vN2QXZGnc&t=6m47s) has a few interesting equations on the topic:

[image]

Men basically have a testosterone peak in the morning, an evening low, and a fluctuating peak every 2 or so hours throughout the day.

In other words, yes, there is a hormone peak in the morning. I've no idea if it's at that specific time for every male. But this is far from controversial or novel - the first time I heard this was over 20 years ago, and I'd gather it had then been known for quite a while.

Females have [two peaks in sexual activity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95OP9rSjxzw&t=20m4s): one during peak fertility (which is hormonal), and another towards the end of their cycle (because no risk of babies).

Comment: This is based on one TED talk, and the equations are presented without  stating what the variables in them stand for, and backed up only by the presenter saying "I promise you these are real".

Comment: @DJClayworth: The first quoted speaker wrote an entire book on the topic of maths and sex. The second is a Stanford professor and widely recognized by his peers.

Comment: This would be good information to put in the answer.

Comment: I'm not following how a peak in a hormone entails it's immediately "best for sex". Spermatogenesis takes fairly long time, [at least 74 days in humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermatogenesis#Duration).

Comment: Also, testosterone (apart from pathologically low levels) doesn't matter for erection: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16651047